# How do I pass command to mongoimport using python os.system()? upsertFields has spaces

Tags: python, windows, command-line, mongoimport

I am trying to import file into mongoDb.

Python 3.7, mongoimport, windows.
It works perfectly with fields without space.

```
command = '"D:\\Program Files\\bin\\mongoimport.exe" -c _ --mode=merge --upsertFields="Current url",Title -d _  --file="D:\\folder\\folder\\temp.json" --jsonArray'
os.system(command)
```

Result:
'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I think it can be related to escaping but don't know exactly.

I've tried

```
c2 = ["D:\\Program Files\\bin\\mongoimport.exe", '-c _ --mode=merge --upsertFields="Current url",Title -d _ --file="D:\\audiotorah\\audiotorah\\temp.json" --jsonArray']

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(c2,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize =0)
```

But it never stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid escaping, append an `r` before the string to make it a raw string.

Using `os.system`:

```
import os

command = r'"D:\Program Files\bin\mongoimport.exe" -c _ --mode=merge --upsertFields="Current url",Title -d _ --file="D:\folder\folder\temp.json" --jsonArray'
os.system(command)
```

Using `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess, shlex

command = r'"D:\Program Files\bin\mongoimport.exe" -c _ --mode=merge --upsertFields="Current url",Title -d _ --file="D:\audiotorah\audiotorah\temp.json" --jsonArray'
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: It does not work. 'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. -- os.system